# how to inject defer in scripts tag of index.html after angular build

Tags: angular, deferred-loading

i want to defer load my vendor.js  bundle in angular app. which approach should i look for as there is no direct way to defer load bundle in angular.
this is my src index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>DeferLoding</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body class="mat-typography">
    <app-root></app-root>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think you can.

Comment: Please pay attention to correct capitalisation.

Comment: Which angular version are you using? I believe from version 8 that should be done automatically